# Has_secure_password Bcrypt giving nil password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I am trying to follow along to Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rail book and I am at Chapter 10, trying to allow users to edit their profile settings, and this is the most bizarre error- bcrypt's password_digest is sabotaging my tests.

**users.yml**

```
user:
  name: Example User
  email: example@gmail.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest("password") %>
```

When I run this in rails console, this is what I see

*user.valid?* => **false**

*user.errors.full_messages*
=> **["Password can't be blank", "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]**

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  before_save {
   self.email.downcase!
  }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  has_secure_password

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
               BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

I am using bcrypt version '3.1.11'

**My test code**

```
 def setup
    @user = users(:marko)
  end

  test "successful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    name = "Foo bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: {
                                          name: name,
                                          email: email,
                                          password: "password",
                                          password_confirmation: "password" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name, @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: try just providing the `password` in yml. The digest should be created automatically.

Comment: Have tried this, I get `ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "password"`.

Comment: How is your test code like?

Comment: Will add my test code to the question, though I was able to replicate the problem in console

Comment: Ok, so i decided to plow forward without testing doing some entirely unrelated things. And for some inexplicable reason- the test fixed itself.  While it makes sense because nothing I found on the internet was plaguing my code, I am hesitant as the problem left as randomly as it came. TL;DR- this question has no answer. for now, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
user:
  name: Example User
  email: example@gmail.com
  password: "password"
```

Bcrypt has a validation that `password` `attr_accessor` should be present while creating a new record (***optional while updating it***).

Also you should add `allow_blank: true` to your `length validation` for password because length validation is not needed when password itself is **empty/nil**

Answer (score 0):

Having a fixture like this one:

```
some_user:
  name: Some user
  email: some_user@example.com
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('secret') %>
```

Will create a user with that data directly to the database.

Then when validating the model, you must implement a validation like this one:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, allow_blank: true }
```

Note that you shouldn't validate the `presence`.

That's because in the form you will be asking for a `password`, with that name, not a `password_digest` (which is the final field saved into the DB table).

Rails will then validate that "fake" or intermediate password field, and if it passes, then it generates the digest and it leaves the password field out. That's why you must add `allow_blank: true`, so tests can pass.